# How can I add/remove instances from GCE load balancers with Ansible?

Tags: google-compute-engine, ansible, google-cloud-platform

I see that there is a [gce_lb](http://docs.ansible.com/gce_lb_module.html) Ansible module, but it is unclear to me whether or not I can actually use this to change the instances assigned to that LB or whether the module just creates and destroys LBs.

In contrast, EC2 clearly has [one module](http://docs.ansible.com/ec2_elb_lb_module.html) just for creating and destroying ELBs, and [another module](http://docs.ansible.com/ec2_elb_module.html) explicitly for [de]registering instances to/from an existing ELB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, the gce_lb module is only for creating/destroying the LB. It does not support adding/removing instances.

The GCE modules in Ansible are built on top of the python libcloud library which *does* have support for add/remove. I think a similar approach taken by the EC2 modules would be a good solution here also.

Comment: I did note that there appears to be add/remove support in libcloud, so I'll go that route - thanks